# CQ 5 Query builder: to get list of pages without jcr:content node

Tags: aem

Using the Query Builder (`http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html`), I would want to get a list of pages that do not have a `jcr:content` child node.

I tried with node, item name etc., but could not find the correct query. Appreciate your help.

```
    path=/content/products
    type=cq:Page
    node=jcr:content
    node.operation=exists
    node.operation=not
    p.limit=-1
```

Comment: The URL you are providing is not accessible from the outside. If the information in that URL is important, please add a screenshot of it to your question, so people can see it.

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio In this case, this is the URL of the Query Builder debug console in CQ, so it's standard functionality. I think the question is valid as it stands

Answer (score 3):

CQ5 Query Builder transforms provided query into a Jackrabbit XPath query. The latter doesn't support testing the child existence. Following XPath theoretically should work:

```
/jcr:root/content//element(*, cq:Page)[not(jcr:content)]
```

but the result is empty. There is a [JIRA improvement](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-1447) to add such feature, but it looks abandoned.

So, we have to check it manually. Because CQ predicates doesn't offer such feature (there is no `node` predicate that you used in your query) we need to write a new predicate:

```
@Component(metatype = false, factory = "com.day.cq.search.eval.PredicateEvaluator/child")
public class ChildrenPredicateEvaluator extends AbstractPredicateEvaluator {

    public boolean includes(Predicate p, Row row, EvaluationContext context) {
        final Resource resource = context.getResource(row);

        final String name = p.get("name", "");
        final boolean childExists;
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            childExists = resource.hasChildren();
        } else {
            childExists = resource.getChild(name) != null;
        }

        final String operator = p.get("operator", "exists");
        if ("not_exists".equals(operator)) {
            return !childExists;
        } else {
            return childExists;
        }
    }

    public boolean canXpath(Predicate predicate, EvaluationContext context) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean canFilter(Predicate predicate, EvaluationContext context) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

We can use it as follows:

```
child.name=wantedChild
child.operator=exists

// or

child.name=unwantedChild
child.operator=not_exists
```

You may also skip the `child.name` line to check if any children exist / don't exist.

So, your query using this predicate would look like this:

```
path=/content/products
type=cq:Page
child.name=jcr:content
child.operator=not_exists
p.limit=-1
```